# Draw Route fron Point A to Point B in GoogleMap for Android Auto

Tags: android, android-maps, android-auto

I'm using Android SDK for maps in my application to render a Map for AndroidAuto inside a SurfaceCallBack. I can draw polilynes (directly), markers, etc. But I need a route from A to B.

This is my surfacecallback method

```
@Override
            public void onSurfaceAvailable(@NonNull SurfaceContainer surfaceContainer) {
                if (!isSurfaceReady(surfaceContainer)) {
                    return;
                }

                    LatLng pointA = new LatLng(19.433364, -99.130031);
                    LatLng pointB = new LatLng(19.437652, -99.133152);

                    mSurface = surfaceContainer.getSurface();
                    VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay = mCarContext
                            .getSystemService(DisplayManager.class)
                            .createVirtualDisplay(
                                    "nameVD",
                                    surfaceContainer.getWidth(),
                                    surfaceContainer.getHeight(),
                                    surfaceContainer.getDpi(),
                                    surfaceContainer.getSurface(),
                                    DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY);

                    Presentation presentation = new Presentation(mCarContext, virtualDisplay.getDisplay());

                    NavigationViewForAuto navigationView = new NavigationViewForAuto(mCarContext);
                    navigationView.onCreate(null);
                    navigationView.onStart();
                    navigationView.onResume();

                    presentation.setContentView(navigationView);
                    presentation.show();

                    navigationView.getMapAsync(googleMap -> {
                        mBackgroundMap = googleMap;
                        centerMapOnCurrentLocation();
                        addRoute(pointA, pointB);
                        renderFrame(); // Render the frame once the map is ready
                    });
            }
```

Im using this library:

```
implementation ("com.google.android.libraries.navigation:navigation:5.2.0")
```

AddRoute function just draw a line